# Error when using TO_DATE in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, to-date

I understand the basic TO_DATE usage in Oracle SQL. i google and found some guides to use TO_DATE which is to convert julien date to normal date.

the basic working code is :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR((TO_DATE(2016365, 'YYYYDDD'))) FROM DUAL)
```

However, i want to convert date that is in a column which has thousands of them.
What i did was :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR((TO_DATE(PREVDT, 'YYYYDDD'))) FROM DUAL)
```

The changes is PREVDT because all my julian date is in PREVDT column. However, im getting invalid identifier.....can anyone help me?

I also tried this but no luck:

```
TO_CHAR((TO_DATE(PREVDT, 'YYYYDDD')))
```

Comment: change it to `FROM your_table_name;` not `FROM DUAL`

Comment: Passing the converted date through `TO_CHAR()` without specifying a format model converts that date back to a string using your session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting - it is no longer a date. That probably isn't what you really want to do - either leave it as a date, or specify the format if you do want it back as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the table name in which your column `PREVDT` is present.

```
select TO_CHAR((TO_DATE(PREVDT, 'YYYYDDD'))) FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle DUAL table does not have the column `PREVDT`. What you want to do is run the query against your table, the one with column PREVDT.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR((TO_DATE(PREVDT, 'YYYYDDD'))) FROM your_table_name;
```

The `PREVDT` values should be in the specified date format otherwise you will get an error.

Read more about the DUAL table [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries009.htm).